# Node debugger no longer listens/attaches to process launched through launch.json in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I use VSCode to work on my own small Discord bot using Node and the DJS library, and the Node debugger used to attach itself without input on my end when I launched the process through the Run and Debug menu. I took quite a long break from working on it, came back recently to rewrite everything, and it just... fails to do so now.

Using `Node --inspect` and attaching the debugger manually works, though it doesn't agree very well with my workflow. It does work, but it is only a workaround in the end... I have spent a few hours trying to find info on why it no longer attaches in the way it used to, but to summarise a very long search: For all intents and purposes, it has no reason to... not work.

I don't believe that the issue lies within the `launch.json` file since it matches every layout I've seen online, as well as my old `launch.json` file (which also no longer works), and I have Auto-Attach set to Always. Long story short, I am at a complete loss and at the end of my limited knowledge.